# A family Mersenne composite numbers?

Tags: nt.number-theory

I believe that the number

$$2^{2^{2t+1}+2t-1}-1$$

is composite for all positive integer $t$. I tested this for many $t$'s, but so far I didn't get a proof. Any idea?

Comment: Hmm, so you mean $M=2^m-1$ where $m=2^{2t+1}-1+2t=4\cdot 2^w+w $. If $m$ is composite, then $M$ must also be composite. So it might be easier to prove that $m$ is composite?

Comment: @GottfriedHelms $m$ can be prime e.g. $t=71$.

Comment: $4*2^w+w$ is prime (or at least prp) for $w=141,411,5495,6647,7427,7889,14565,17933,...$

Comment: The first possible prime is for $2^m-1,m=11150372599265311570767859136324180752990349,t=71$. PRP test is not tractable for current hardware unless it is divisible by small primes.

Comment: @Joro: true; for some small $t$ the factorizing looked a bit systematic, but in a second view for larger $t$ that simple pattern did not hold.

Comment: I did a tiny amount of trial factoring: any prime factor of $2^m-1$ with $t=71$ is larger than $2^{172}$.

Comment: @TapioRajala might be missing something, but is $2^{172}$ typo? I am pretty sure you can't hold the number in RAM/swap so you are computing $N \mod p$ for small $p$ and check if it is zero. Are you using different approach?

Comment: @joro No typo there. Any prime factor is of the form $k*2m+1$. I calculated $2^m \mod p$ with all primes of that form for $k$ up to $2^{28}$.

Comment: For which $t$'s did you test this (i.e. have a proof)?

Answer (score 4):

If your expression is composite for all large $t$, then either (a) $4\cdot 2^w+w$ is composite for all large $w$ or (b) $2^p-1$ is composite for infinitely many primes $p$. Now (a) is probably false while (b) is probably (surely!) true --- however, no one has succeeded in showing (b) unconditionally!

Comment: :-) Nice approach to sort things out...